# Issue with Shibboleth SP Compilation and Installation on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, shibboleth

I followed the steps below to install Shibboleth SP on Ubuntu 14.04

Installed the pre-requisite packages

```
sudo apt-get install --yes wget gcc g++ make libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev apache2-threaded-dev
```

Created directories

```
mkdir -p ~/build-shib
sudo mkdir -p /opt/shibboleth-sp/etc/shibboleth
```

Downloaded and installed the following

```
cd ~/build-shib
wget http://www.shibboleth.net/downloads/log4shib/1.0.4/log4shib-1.0.4.tar.gz
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.1.1.tar.gz
wget http://www.apache.org/dist/santuario/c-library/xml-security-c-1.6.1.tar.gz
wget http://www.shibboleth.net/downloads/c++-opensaml/2.4.3/xmltooling-1.4.2.tar.gz
wget http://www.shibboleth.net/downloads/c++-opensaml/2.4.3/opensaml-2.4.3.tar.gz
wget http://www.shibboleth.net/downloads/service-provider/2.4.3/shibboleth-sp-2.4.3.tar.gz

tar xvfz log4shib-1.0.4.tar.gz
tar xvfz xerces-c-3.1.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz xml-security-c-1.7.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz xmltooling-1.4.2.tar.gz
tar xvfz opensaml-2.4.3.tar.gz
tar xvfz shibboleth-sp-2.5.3.tar.gz

cd ~/build-shib/log4shib-1.0.4 
./configure --disable-static --disable-doxygen --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp && make && sudo make install

cd ~/build-shib/xerces-c-3.1.1
./configure --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp && make && sudo make install

cd ~/build-shib/xml-security-c-1.7.2
./configure --without-xalan --disable-static --with-xerces=/opt/shibboleth-sp --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp && make && sudo make install

cd ~/build-shib/xmltooling-1.4.2
./configure --with-log4shib=/opt/shibboleth-sp --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp -C && make && sudo make install 

cd ~/build-shib/opensaml-2.4.3
./configure --prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp --with-log4shib=/opt/shibboleth-sp -C && make && sudo make install

cd ~/build-shib/shibboleth-2.5.3
./configure --with-saml=/opt/shibboleth-sp --enable-apache-22 --with-log4shib=/opt/shibboleth-sp --with-xmltooling=/opt/shibboleth-sp \
--prefix=/opt/shibboleth-sp -C && make && sudo make install
```

When I try to check if Shibboleth SP is compiled properly with

```
ldd /opt/shibboleth-sp/bbin/shibd | grep /opt/shibboleth-sp/lib
```

I get the following error

```
ldd: /opt/shibboleth-sp/bin/shibd: No such file or directory
```

On checking the contents in `/opt/shibboleth-sp/bin/`, I see that there is no `shibd`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the *shibd* was available at `/opt/shibboleth-sp/sbin/` after source compilation. I have a 64-bit CPU architecture with Ubuntu 14.04. I am not sure if that affects.